# remove/filter data from power bi modeling tab

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a very large data set and would like to remove `n` rows from the bottom up.

For example, if I had `15` numbers: `1 1 2 3 4 5 5 6 7 7 7 8 8 9 9`, and I want to remove 5 entries from the bottom, being `7 8 8 9 9`.

How can I do this in `dax`, remove/filter out `n` rows from the bottom of my data?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to do it using DAX after your data is already loaded? I would think it would make more sense to do it in the query editor.

Comment: yes I would really prefer to do so I’m dax. The reason is I made a new column in the modeling tab and want to use the values in that new column do remove n rows from the whole dataset

Comment: Have you tried the `TOPN()` function?

Comment: Yes, this is my code `Measure = TOPN((COUNTROWS(Age) - COUNTROWS(Age)*0.025), AgeTable)` but I get this error `The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.`

Comment: You can't do that as a measure (since a measure only returns a single value), but it should work fine if you input it as a formula for a New Table.